# Unable to delete ghost server from dbo.keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting this error in the SSRS

> SSRS: The feature: “Scale-out deployment” is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

So I tried to delete an entry from `dbo.keys` as suggested in multiple forums.

```
delete from keys 
where MachineName = 'YourGhostServer'
```

But, the entry is appearing again once I restart the services

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've restored a copy of the `ReportServer` DB from another instance or similar?

If you open the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, and connect to your instance, how many servers do in see in the Scale-out Deployment screen? If 2, then select the one that shouldn't be there and click Remove Server. (Screen from a 2012 instance, that doesn't have 2 servers; yours *should* look similar):

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing the list of servers in this tab

Comment: Could you add an image to your post? Seeing no servers infers something much more wrong.